# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression when defining interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im trying to build a form and start by defining an interface

```js
interface
TokenListProps
{
  readonly
  contractAddress: string;
}
```

and I get a compile error 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression' for this line.

Any suggestions on why this might be?

Comment: Too many newlines, perhaps, but hard to say without context for how it's being compiled etc.

Comment: can you be more specific? should it all be on one line?

Comment: No, but you can't arbitrarily break up lines like `interface TokenListProps` or the `readonly` modifier. [For example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsDWEQBlgDOYAClOgA4HIDeAUMslBHACbogA2Ansgu2FERgAgixZMCBAFzIiUUAHMA3LQC+tIA)

Comment: @mleafer If my answer solved your issue, please accept it for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the info you have provided the issue is the newlines in your definitions.

You currently have this:

```
interface
TokenListProps
{
  readonly
  contractAddress: string;
}
```

And it should be like this:

```
interface TokenListProps
{
  readonly contractAddress: string;
}
```